# addPersistentStoreWithType fails in Core Data

Tags: core-data

Does a core data database location have to be under the app's applicationDocumentsDirectory?  That is how it is behaving for me.

I would like to create my core data database in a folder of my choosing; however, when I attempt to create it outside of the applicationDocumentsDirectory, it fails.

Works fine:
databaseURL path: Users/rickschlueter/Library/Containers/com.eBetsy.eBetsy/Data/Library/Application%20Support
[coordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:self.storeDataURL options:options error:&error]

Fails:
databaseURL path : Users/rickschlueter/Pictures/Inventory%20Database
error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=512 "The file couldn’t be saved." UserInfo={reason=Failed to create file; code = 1}

Comment: This is a Mac app?

Comment: Do you have sandboxing turned on? You can't write to any arbitrary location if it is.